# How to increase digital input pins of Arduino using 74HC574

Tags: arduino, flipflop, pins, shift-register

I've been working on a project with an Arduino. I need to use many TCRT5000 IR modules and I'm out of pins. I also used a DC motor driver shield and it also took a lot of pins.

Now I need to increase my two or three pins to lot more with a 74HC574n flip-flop module. I was going to buy a 74HC595 but I made a mistake and now I have a 74HC574n. It is not possible to buy the one I wanted, so I have to use what I already have.

Any ideas about it? I would be pleased if you could help me. Thanks.

Comment: You want an "I/O expander".    i.e.  https://www.mouser.com/c/semiconductors/interface-ics/interface-i-o-expanders/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIg9iyqvmL-QIV8PvjBx0qdQ93EAAYAiAAEgIP9vD_BwE    You're welcome  :)

Comment: I guess it'll work with those I/O expanders. I'll try that too. But for now I need something like a module or something that it is ready and doesn't need to prepare it to use. 
Also I prefer to use this IC that I already have if it is possible. I can't buy the exact same thing that you're telling me to buy. because I'm in Iran and there isn't much rare things. @Kyle B

Comment: You say you want to expand the *inputs*, but the 595 would allow you to expand the outputs (it has no parallel inputs). What are you really trying to do? Expanding inputs or outputs or both?

Comment: Yes Umm I want to expand the inputs but also its ok if I find out a way to expand outputs.

Answer (score 1):

If you can only use 74HC574n parts, and you know how to do it with 74HC595 parts ...

74HC574n is 8 D FFs with a common clock.

74HC595 is a serial-in, parallel out register.

Use one 74HC574n to make a shift register. Wire the Q out to the next D in. You need 2 MCU pins, D and serial Clock.

Use a second 74HC574n for the latch. The Data comes from the first part. You need 1 MCU pin to clock the second FF and latch the data.

Three MCU pins total. Less efficient, for an 8-bit output port, you need 2 20-pin parts instead of 1 16-pin part.